# Azure IoT Hub - Device Registration in portable library

Tags: c#, .net, azure, nuget-package, iot

I need to use Microsoft.Azure.Devices in .NET Portable library
I found Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.PCL Nuget package for part of functionality but no Microsoft.Azure.Devices for code bellow.
- I need to register new device / find if there is existing to retrieve device Key - Is there any way to do this inside portable library?

```
registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
device = await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(new Device(deviceID));
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe there is at this time. I looked at the package, there is no PCL in there. I don't see why this cant be made it a NuGet package that can be called from a PCL. You can even look into building a [Bait and Switch package](http://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/) to support your specific scenario.

The code for the IOT client is available [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/csharp/device/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client) under the MIT license and you can repackage this to work for your scenario so that it can be called from a PCL.